# Dplyr / tidyverse How to order columns first by number of available values and second by alphabetical order?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to reorder my dataset to have in first position the columns with less NA and if columns have equal Na, use alphabetical order.

```
tonnage <- c(NA, NA, 280, 890)
tonnage2 <- c(NA, NA, 567, 899)
year1 <- c(1990, 2018, 1889, 2000)
id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
tonnage3 <- c(NA, 456, 567, 899)

dataset <- data.frame(tonnage, tonnage2, year1, id, tonnage3)
```

What Can I do :

```
 # order column alpha
dataset %>%
  select(sort(names(.)))

 # Count number of available values and sort
 sort(colSums(!is.na(dataset)))
```

What I want : id, year1, tonnage3, tonnage, tonnage2.

Comment: your example does not run

Comment: @Sotos I corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `colSums` to count number of `NA` in each column, `sort` the values, extract the names and use it to subset the dataframe.

```
dataset[names(sort(colSums(is.na(dataset))))]

#  year1 id tonnage3 tonnage tonnage2
#1  1990  1       NA      NA       NA
#2  2018  2      456      NA       NA
#3  1889  3      567     280      567
#4  2000  4      899     890      899
```

To use it in pipes, you can use the same in `select`.

```
library(dplyr)
dataset %>% select(names(sort(colSums(is.na(.)))))
```

---

Just realized that the above does not sort alphabetically in case of equal `NA`. We can do

```
cols <- sort(colSums(is.na(dataset)))
dataset[unlist(tapply(names(cols), cols, sort))]

#  id year1 tonnage3 tonnage tonnage2
#1  1  1990       NA      NA       NA
#2  2  2018      456      NA       NA
#3  3  1889      567     280      567
#4  4  2000      899     890      899
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your columns are first ordered alphabetically, and then use `colSums` on your NAs and sort via that number,

i.e.

```
dataset <- dataset[order(gsub('\\D+', '', names(dataset)))]

#then sort on number of NAs,
dataset[names(sort(colSums(is.na(dataset))))]
```

which gives,

> ```
>    id year1 tonnage3 tonnage tonnage2
> 1  1  1990       NA      NA       NA
> 2  2  2018      456      NA       NA
> 3  3  1889      567     280      567
> 4  4  2000      899     890      899
> ```